# download image in php

Tags: php, image, download

i have a problem in my code php 
i make wallpaper script 
After upload image the name of image is saved in the database and image saved in the file (images/)
i want after show image in page php and click download 
i want to download image in desktop

but after click in download the image saved in desktop but But be empty
see this image : http://im51.gulfup.com/riod8Y.png

my code

```
<?php
$getpic = $db->query('SELECT *','wallpaper',$where = array(
                                'id',
                                '=',
                                "".$id.""
                              ));
        $row = mysql_fetch_object($getpic);

        $file = 'images/'.$row->image;

          if($_POST['download']){
          if (file_exists($file)) {
              header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
              header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
              header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
              header('Expires: 0');
              header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
              header('Pragma: public');
              header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
              readfile($file);
              exit;
          }
          }
          ?>
```

Comment: Did you try `echo $file = 'images/'.$row->image; exit;` to see if that is a valid image link?

Comment: If it is a valid image link, did you try using a prepended root like: `__DIR__.'/images/'.$row->image;`?

Comment: not working @Rasclatt

Comment: When you echoed the link was it a valid link?